# Change Eclipse Indigo Debug Appereance

Tags: eclipse, settings, preferences, appearance

I have a problem with Eclipse Preference. I cannot see anything in the debug-layout which pops up when you hover over a variable, but sometimes pictures can say more than words:

[image: balck Background on Eclipse Debug]

how can I adjust the colors for that (especially the Background Color), as it appears sometimes in Eclipses Menus as well.

EDIT: According to the first answer

I tried to set to default with no result. I also cannot follow your provided guide to find debug_background option. Here is the output from Eclipse if I type Appearance inside:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think I have a good answer for you, but I have my own experience. Based on what I see in your illustration, you're not running Ubuntu/GNOME, so my answer may not satisfy you.

This sort of thing is a balance between the underlying OS and the application. For example, on Ubuntu (GNOME, pre-Unity), nothing satisfactory is in my opinion possible short of changing the overall (GNOME) theme. In my case, while I like the default Ubuntu theme, I find I can't see (the same stuff you're showing) adequately unless I resort to Clearlooks. And so I gave up trying to fix this long ago with Eclipse Preferences and just always go with that theme.

Maybe this will help you or someone else.

Comment: I don't mind to change my theme, and yes, I'm using latest Xubuntu, but I changing thems has no effect of it, at all. btw, I don't have Clearlooks, but will download it and try it

Answer (score 1):

You should modify GTK system theme you are using.

sudo vim /usr/share/themes/%your_theme%/%gtk_you_are_using%/gtkrc

```
style "clearlooks-tooltips" = "clearlooks-default"
{
        xthickness = 4
        ythickness = 4
        bg[NORMAL] = { 0.30,0.30,0.30 }
}
widget "gtk-tooltips" style "clearlooks-tooltips"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Window->Preferences then search `Appearance` in the input box above the categories on the left and clicking `Restore Defaults`?

If you don't want to restore everything there is a Debug sub-folder with background colour option

Comment: please look at my edit, I posted. I couldn't find the debug option

Comment: Sorry I was working with eclipse CDT, I'm guessing it has a different appearance config from the standard java one?

Answer (score 0):

in case somebody bumps into this post and xfce-display-appearance-settings is not a recognised command, as in my case, this command worked for me:

xfce4-appearance-settings

( from http://wiki.xfce.org/faq )
.
I haven't tested the other ones, but the Clearlooks ( Style -> Clearlooks ) solves the problem. I haven't tried any other ones but it probably isn't the only one.